# Como fazer o cálculo do frete de vários produtos

Tags: php, web-service

Estou desenvolvendo uma loja virtual e preciso implementar o cálculo de frete para a compra, consegui fazer essa implementação mas o problema é que com um produto único no carrinho eu obtenho o retorno correto, mas com vários produtos no carrinho os valores não batem com o simulador da empresa de logística.

Eu queria preciso saber como que eu faço para calcular o frete de vários produtos juntos. Se eu faço o cálculo da cubagem de cada um separado e depois somo todos, ou se faço o cálculo da cubagem com a soma das dimensões dos produtos, ou qual é a forma correta de fazer isso.

Estou perdido com relação a esse cálculo pois não na internet só existe conteúdo explicando à respeito do cálculo de produtos individuais e não consigo resolver essa questão.

Comment: Olha, quando eu faço com os correios eu sempre somo o peso de todos para fazer o calculo, acho que o correto seria fazer o calculo da cubagem com a soma das dimensões.

Answer (score 4):

Para fazer um cálculo que bata com o da empresa de logística, você teria que fazer o mesmo cálculo que eles fazem. Cada empresa pode ser seu próprio critério:

- apenas peso
- dimensão: largura + altura + profundidade não ultrapassando um valor estabelecido (tipo empresa aérea: a soma da largura + altura + profundidade não pode ultrapassar 115 cm)
- dimensão: na combinação de tamanho dos produtos ser possível montar uma caixa com limites
  máximos de largura, altura e profundidade, e tendo o problema de  otimizar seus produtos para caberem nesta caixa
- um valor fixo para o primeiro pacote e depois um valor menor para cada pacote extra
- um valor fixo para o primeiro quilo e um valor menor para cada quilo extra
- uma combinação de qualquer regra acima.

Se as regras estiverem em algum site, use as regras que eles explicam (por ex., você utilizar os Correios do Brasil, poderá ver as regras no site deles)

Se não estiverem, apenas perguntando e recebendo a resposta deles.

E se eles fornecerem uma interface que você possa acessar, faça seu programa informar os dados para eles e eles que calculem para você, se o seu contrato com eles permitir.

Infelizmente, qualquer resposta sem saber qual a sua empresa de logística ou os critérios que eles usam serão apenas dicas gerais e especulação, sendo difícil te ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

A questão vai além de somar as dimensões e pesos, o correto é definir caixas padrões e com a soma dos produtos identificar se caberão nela...

Pois se apenas somarmos os valores, pode ocorrer de exceder o limite permitido pelos Correios.

O que pode ser feito:
Exemplo: Caixa 1 (20 x 20 x 20), Caixa 2 (30 x 30 x 40)........... ao acrescentar mais de 1 produto, deve ser somado suas dimensões e fazer a verificação, OS PRODUTOS CABEM NA CAIXA 1?... OS PRODUTOS CABEM NA CAIXA 2??, se as dimensões excederem as caixas cadastradas, desmembre a cotação... terá que cotar produtos individualmente.

Pode parecer um pouco complicado, mas diminui a possibilidade de erros e sempre acaba ganhando um pouquinho no valor do frete.